# null return in Listview.Builder

Tags: json, flutter, listview, dart, arraylist

i have this function which give me a json

```
     var url = '.....';
  Future getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    data=responsebody["rates"]
    print(data);
```

when i print the responsebody its show me the result on the consol
but when i try call it with Listview.builder its returning null

```
 return ListTile(title: Text(data[i]["rates"]["USD"])
```

also i tried that an no result

```
return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[i]["rates"]["USD"])
```

my json

```
{
timestamp: 1617161125,
base: "USD",
rates: {
USD: 1,
BGN: 1.74474,
ILS: 3.3407,
GBP: 0.72863,
ETH: 0.00054,
DKK: 6.35326,
CAD: 1.26226,
JPY: 110.86172,
HUF: 310.86,
RON: 4.1481,
UAH: 28.475,
XAG: 4.2006,
SEK: 8.7484,
SGD: 1.34751,
HKD: 7.77603,
AUD: 1.31484,
CHF: 0.9442,
XAU: 5.95507,
CNY: 6.5719,
LTC: 0.00517,
HRK: 9.49818,
NZD: 1.43277,
LVL: 0.55989,
EUR: 0.85415,
TRY: 8.3537,
NOK: 8.56244,
RUB: 75.9939,
INR: 73.5781,
MXN: 20.61,
CZK: 22.357,
BRL: 5.7736,
BTC: 0.00002,
PLN: 3.985,
ZAR: 14.9495
}
```

}

my Listview.builder code:

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          return ListView.builder(
             itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
              

              return ListTile(title: Text(data[i]["rates"]["USD"])
                
                  );
            },
          );
        }));
```

Comment: Please add your json and future builder.

Comment: thanke you for your comment,please check the update i have added them

Comment: I think you need to return `data` in your `getdata()` method @AliMahdiyar

Comment: `return data;`  like this

Comment: that was an a problem too

Comment: This is a lot of guesswork, because your code contains multiple problems, but some of them could be due to omissions when posting here. So next time, please try to post a [mcve] so we can say for sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this,

`Text(snapshot.data["USD"].toString())`, because your currency is an integer, and it should work.

As mentioned in the comments also, you need to return data in your function.

Comment: Text(snapshot.data["USD"].tostring())

Comment: Added it and return data.